# Spring boot not scanning classes after spring boot main class moving to separate package

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I put my spring boot main class in a separate package "config.init" and used @ComponentScan annotation to scan all other classes but I am getting below error. I have also tried using @SpringBootApplication (scanBasePackages="all packages") annotation, but getting the same issue.

```
2017-04-03 21:08:20.101  INFO 9784 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-04-03 21:08:20.220  INFO 9784 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-04-03 21:08:20.276  WARN 9784 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.alokpanda.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2017-04-03 21:08:20.277  INFO 9784 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-04-03 21:08:20.290  WARN 9784 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2017-04-03 21:08:20.702 ERROR 9784 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.alokpanda.service.impl.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.alokpanda.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.alokpanda.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.

2017-04-03 21:08:20.715 ERROR 9784 --- [ina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringLogin]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringLogin]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.alokpanda.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.alokpanda.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.alokpanda.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted

2017-04-03 21:08:20.717 ERROR 9784 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355) [bootstrap.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) [bootstrap.jar:8.5.13]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2017-04-03 21:08:20.718 ERROR 9784 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina     : The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355) [bootstrap.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) [bootstrap.jar:8.5.13]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.13]
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2017-04-03 21:08:20.719  INFO 9784 --- [           main] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol     : Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
2017-04-03 21:08:20.719  INFO 9784 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Catalina
2017-04-03 21:08:20.723  INFO 9784 --- [           main] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol     : Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

my classes structure

[classes and packages structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8eYH.png)

spring boot web initializer class

```
package com.alokpanda.config.init;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringLoginApplication.class);
    }

}
```

spring boot main class

```
package com.alokpanda.config.init;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.alokpanda.config.init", "com.alokpanda.controller.rest", "com.alokpanda.repository", "com.alokpanda.service.impl"})
public class SpringLoginApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringLoginApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

UserRestController

```
package com.alokpanda.controller.rest;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.alokpanda.model.User;
import com.alokpanda.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<User> onGetRequest() {

        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

User (Model Class)

```
package com.alokpanda.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Past;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Min(0)
    @Column(name="ID", length=10)
    private Integer id;

    @Size(min=2, max=50)
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+")
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="NAME", length=50, nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Size(min=1, max=1)
    @Column(name="GENDER")
    private String gender;

    @Past
    @Column(name="DATE_OF_BIRTH", nullable=true)
    private Date dob;

    @Size(min=5, max=50)
    @Column(name="EMAIL", length=50, nullable=false)
    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + ", dob=" + dob + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(Integer id, String name, String gender, Date dob, String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
package com.alokpanda.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.alokpanda.model.User;

@Repository                                     
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    //Entity class (User) and entity class id type (Integer)

}
```

UserService

```
package com.alokpanda.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.alokpanda.model.User;

public interface UserService {

    public List<User> getAllUsers();

}
```

UserServiceImpl

```
package com.alokpanda.service.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.alokpanda.model.User;
import com.alokpanda.repository.UserRepository;
import com.alokpanda.service.UserService;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
        userRepository.findAll()
        .forEach(list :: add);
        return list;
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

security.basic.enabled=false
```

Comment: please refer this post in `Spring Boot Documentation`.I suppose you need to restructure the project. [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)

Comment: What value exactly did you specify within the annotation `@SpringBootApplication("valuehere")`? If that is configured correctly, it should work.

Comment: @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.alokpanda.config.init", "com.alokpanda.controller.rest", "com.alokpanda.repository", "com.alokpanda.service.impl"})

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities:

Either configure the package in `@SpringBootApplication`:

```
@SpringBootApplication("com.alokpanda")
```

Or add the following to enable the JPA repository scanning in the correct package:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.alokpanda")
```

If you specify the package in `@SpringBootApplication`, Spring Boot will configure the packages for all necessary scanning (this includes JPA repositories, component scanning, entity scanning). If you only specify packages in `@ComponentScan`, you have to specify the other annotations as well to take effect.

Comment: @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.alokpanda") getting same error

Comment: Because you also need `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.alokpanda").` I strongly suggest moving your application to the top level package as that will reduce the amount of configuration you need to do. Spring Boot will scan everything in all the sub packages the `@SpringBootApplication` class is in, if yu move that to a seperate package it scans only that. Which also means you need to enable all other things manually. (Like `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` (or whatever your persistence provider is).

Comment: But shouldn't the package which you specify in SpringBootApplication also be applied to EntityScan and EnableJpaRepositories? I thought i read that somewhere in the documentation.